# clipspy: How to get slot dictionary of instance

Tags: python, clips, clipspy

The [documentation](https://clipspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) contains this example code:

```
...
klass = env.find_class('MyClass')
instance = klass.new_instance('instance-name')
instance['One'] = 1
instance['Two'] = 2
```

Is there a built-in feature that gives me a dictionary of the slots and their values? Like the `.Slots()` method of `pyclips`.

Something like this:

```
def get_slot_dict(clips_instance):
    slot_dict = {}
    for s in clips_instance.instance_class.slots():
        slot_dict[s.name] = clips_instance[s.name]
    return slot_dict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `clipspy` 0.3.0 you can iterate over the objects metadata to construct your data structures.

```
implied_fact = env.assert_string("(implied-fact 1 2 3)")
list(implied_fact)

[1, 2, 3]

template_fact = env.assert_string("(template-fact (template-slot a-symbol))")

list(template_fact)
[('template-slot', 'a-symbol')]

dict(template_fact)
{'template-slot': 'a-symbol'}

klass = env.find_class('MY-CLASS')
instance = klass.new_instance('instance-name')
instance['One'] = 1
instance['Two'] = 2

dict(instance)
{'One': 1, 'Two': 2}
```